# Postgres index-only scan taking too long

Tags: database, postgresql, query-optimization, rdbms

I have a table with the below structure and indexes:

```
     Table "public.client_data"
         Column          |  Type   | Modifiers 
-------------------------+---------+-----------
 account_id              | text    | not_null
 client_id               | text    | not null
 client_type             | text    | not null
 creation_time           | bigint  | not null
 last_modified_time      | bigint  | not null

 Indexes:
    "client_data_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (account_id, client_id)
    "client_data_last_modified_time_index" btree (last_modified_time)
```

From this table I need to find the oldest record -  for this I used the following query:

```
SELECT last_modified_time FROM client_data ORDER BY last_modified_time ASC LIMIT 1;
```

However this query on this table with around 61 million rows is running very slow (90-100 mins) in a db.r4.2xlarge RDS instance in AWS Aurora Postgres 9.6 with no other concurrent queries running.

However changing the query to use `DESC` finishes instantly. What could be the problem? I was expecting that since I have an index of the `last_modified_time` querying only for that column ordered by that column with the limit applied would involve an index-only query that should stop after the first entry in the index.

Here is the output of the explain analyze:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT last_modified_time FROM client_data ORDER BY last_modified_time ASC LIMIT 1;

                                                                                                   QUERY PLAN                                                                                                   
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.57..2.31 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=6297823.287..6297823.287 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Index Only Scan using client_data_last_modified_time_index on client_data  (cost=0.57..1049731749.38 rows=606590292 width=8) (actual time=6297823.287..6297823.287 rows=1 loops=1)
         Heap Fetches: 26575013
 Planning time: 0.078 ms
 Execution time: 6297823.306 ms
```

The same for the `DESC` version of the query results in the following

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT last_modified_time FROM client_data ORDER BY last_modified_time DESC LIMIT 1;
                                                                                                 QUERY PLAN                                                                                                  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.57..2.32 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=2.265..2.266 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Index Only Scan Backward using client_data_last_modified_time_index on client_data  (cost=0.57..1066049674.69 rows=611336085 width=8) (actual time=2.264..2.264 rows=1 loops=1)
         Heap Fetches: 9
 Planning time: 0.095 ms
 Execution time: 2.278 ms
```

Any pointers?

Comment: It looks like postgres is visiting the heap often, probably to check on the visibility of older rows.  Is autovacuum keeping up with the changes in this table?

Comment: Not sure, but the auto-vacuum has run recently so may be it is.

Comment: Is it possible that there a lot of **first** identical last_modified_time (with `ASC`), but only a few **last** last_modified_time (with `DESC`)?

Answer (score 1):

The difference is this:

The slow plan has

```
Heap Fetches: 26575013
```

and the fast plan

```
Heap Fetches: 9
```

Heap fetches is what turns a fast index only scan to a slow normal index scan.

Did the table experience mass updates or deletions recently?

The reason for the slow scan is that it has to wade through a lot of invisible (deleted) tuples before it hits the first match.

Run `VACUUM` on the table, and both scans will be fast.

Comment: We do have a deletion operation on the table that deletes data older than 30 days. After the deletion is complete we run the oldest record query for monitoring purposes. When the oldest record query is run, the deletion is has already completed and is not run until the oldest record query is finished. Also the ASC and DESC queries were run multiple times interchangeably and every time the DESC query finishes but the ASC query gets stuck.

Comment: My mistake, I didn't notice the `LIMIT`. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you. I will try that. Your previous link to your article was very informative.